# If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then either $A \in B$ or $A\notin B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Given that $A$ and $B$ are two sets, is the following proposition a tautology:

$A\in B \vee A\notin B$.

I do not know any set theory beyond the naive one.

Comment: Do you mean $A\in B$ or $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: Yes, it is, because $(A \in B) \lor \lnot (A \in B)$ is an istance of the tautology : $\varphi \lor \lnot \varphi$.

Comment: "Either $A$ is a member of $B$ or $A$ is not a member of $B$."  Does that sound like there is any way it could be false?

Comment: @surb sets can be in other sets.

Comment: @ZelosMalum That wouldn't be a tautology.

Comment: @Surb: $\{1\} \in \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, for example

Comment: tertium non datur

Answer (score 15):

Yes, though this has nothing to do with set theory really and is much more about propositional logic. If we replace "$A \in B$" with the propositional variable $\textrm{P}$, then your statement is simply an instance of

$$\textrm{P} \lor \lnot \textrm{P}$$

which is of course always true.

Comment: As Shakespeare said: To be or not to be, that is the question. But this is not a question, this is a simple fact that the statement P∨¬P is always true. :)

Comment: If we were to use propositional logic, then what would be the atoms in this case.

Comment: set theory is a theory, so it depends on a logic, usually classical first-order logic.  in turn, first-order logic includes propositional logic.  The atomic formulas are precisely the sort of thing you've joined with $\lor$ and $\neg$ in your question, things like $A\in B$.

Answer (score 3):

This might depend on the form of logic you are using. It is certainly true if you use "standard" logic. And as has already been pointed out it just follows from basic logical axioms.

Surprisingly though there are (fairly often) used logical systems where the statement $P\vee \neg P$ (called the law of excluded middle) is not provable. An example of this kind of logic is [Intuitionistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) logic.

I must admit that looking at ZFC axioms I don't see how to prove the statement in intuitionistic logic (then again I haven't really used it much). My feeling is that if it does follow it should in some way involve extensionality, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$(A\subset B)\vee (A\not\subset B)\iff (A\subset B)\vee(A\cap B^c\neq\emptyset)$$

which is always true.